# how can i cut off the strings from an output in Bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

The command i run is as follows:

```
rpm -qi setup | grep Install
```

The output of the command:

```
Install Date: Do 30 Jul 2020 15:55:28 CEST
```

I would like to edit this output further more in order to remain with just:
**`30 Jul 2020`**

And the rest of the output not to be displayed.

What best editing way in bash can i possibly simply get this end result?

Comment: ... and what if your installation fails? You will know about the date but you won't know that the installation is not done. So, what's the use? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using just `rpm`queryformat and `bash`printf:

```
$ printf '%(%d %b %Y)T\n' $(rpm -q --queryformat '%{INSTALLTIME}\n' setup)
29 Apr 2020
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep -Po` like so (`-P` = use Perl regex engine, and `-o` = print just the match, not the entire line):

```
echo '**Install Date: Do 30 Jul 2020 15:55:28 CEST**' | grep -Po '\d{1,2}\s+\w{3}\s+\d{4}'
```

You can also use `cut` like so (`-d' '` = split on blanks, `-f4-6` =
print fields 4 through 6):

```
echo '**Install Date: Do 30 Jul 2020 15:55:28 CEST**' | cut -d' ' -f4-6
```

Output:

```
30 Jul 2020
```